# How to create a link that will update a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

I'm using Rails 2.3.8.

How do you create a link that will update a column?

So, I'm trying `<%= link_to 'stuff', :controller => controller, :action => action, :id => id %>`

The `action` method will just update the column of the row associated with `:id`, so I don't want it to redirect to controller/action page. I just want the column updated and call `save` on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use a GET to update anything, always use a POST.  Meaning: A link is bad practice and a security risk.

Comment: You need to post more code.  Do you mean an html column or a database column?  Since you would update a database row, I assume you mean html.  Ajax post and target the results to the element with your id.  I like <td><div id='[id]'> over <td id='[id]'>.

Comment: Sorry about that! It's probably my worst-written question. I added some more details. It seems that my question should be: how to get `link_to` to accomplish a PUT?